# How to use log4j2 jul bridge with custom console appender plugin

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, appender

I have created a appender plugin which writes to the console. It uses following implementation to log in to the console.

```
try {
        final byte[] bytes = getLayout().toByteArray(customLogEvent);
        System.out.write(bytes);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Log event append error",e.getMessage());
     }
```

Now I want to use the same appender to append Java util logs to the console.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the log4j-jul jar to your classpath and set system property `java.util.logging.manager` to the value `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`.

Comment: This application has a configuration file for jul. It contains the following line handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, do I need to change any thing here because still I cannot make it working.

Comment: You will probably want to include these settings in the log4j2.xml configuration. The old JUL configuration will be ignored by log4j2, so once logging calls are routed from JUL to log4j2, only the log4j configuration applies.

Comment: How can I include these setting in log4j2 configuration file ? Is there any sample.

Comment: Take a look at the log4j2 manual pages for File Appender and Console Appender.